# Apple Safari Column Layout Issues on Category pages Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, layout, css, column

I am hoping someone will be able to give me some advice.

I have noticed that when using Apple Safari browser, the columns on our product category pages do not seem to line up. I have the left hand column but the right hand column appears underneath.

Here is an example page if you have Safari: https://www.valvesonline.co.uk/solenoid-valves/brass-solenoid-valves.html

I am not sure if it is a viewport setting or something else.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found it is a CSS issue with display: flex and changed this to display: block and that seems to fix the problem.